# Disable key autogeneration whil importing with Ruby Activerecord Extensions

Tags: ruby, oracle, activerecord, csv, import

I'm trying to use ar-extensions gem to import records from a CSV file into an Oracle table and it is generating the value for the key column via sequence but that value is in my file and I need it to stay like that, is there any way of disabling key auto generation?

This is my code, prepared for a Cucumber task that had to load initial data for a test:

```
    require 'rubygems'
require 'active_record'
require 'CSV'
require 'ar-extensions'

#Logger Objects are handy for finding out why imports crash
logger = Logger.new('import.log')
#Set the Logger level to Info to prevent boring debug messages
logger.level = Logger::INFO

fileName  = " "
tableName = " "
validate = true

ActiveRecord::Base::establish_connection(
    :adapter=>"oracle_enhanced",
    :host=>"192.168.202.123",
    :port=>"1521",
    :database=>"XE",
    :username=>"xxx",
    :password=>"xxx")

#Connect Logger to Active Record
ActiveRecord::Base.logger = logger

class Oacm < ActiveRecord::Base

  self.table_name = "OACM"
  #self.set_primary_key "id_acm"
  self.set_sequence_name :id_acm
  attr_accessible :id_acm
  attr_accessible :descr
  attr_accessible :gp_acm_type_fk
  attr_accessible :chan_fk
  attr_accessible :dt_start
  attr_accessible :dt_end
  attr_accessible :ext_code_ref
  attr_accessible :flg_burn
  attr_accessible :layout_code
  attr_accessible :max_num
  attr_accessible :flg_dpl
  attr_accessible :flg_def
  attr_accessible :flg_state
  attr_accessible :usr_ins
  attr_accessible :ts_ins
  attr_accessible :usr_del
  attr_accessible :ts_del
  attr_accessible :usr_upd
  attr_accessible :ts_upd
  attr_accessible :ver_no
  attr_accessible :ord_no
  attr_accessible :cpccchk
  attr_accessible :ts_dpl
  attr_accessible :ts_dpl
end

def cpccchk_before_type_cast
  cpccchk
end

Given(/^a file named "(.*?)" containing all "(.*?)" data$/) do |arg1, arg2|
  fileName = arg1
  tableName = arg2
  #puts arg1.to_s << " " << arg2.to_s
end

Then(/^it should be loaded$/) do
  preparedRecord = []
  CSV.foreach(fileName, :headers => true) do |row|
    hashedRow = row.to_hash
    puts hashedRow
    #Oacm.id_acm = hashedRow["id_acm"]
    preparedRecord << Oacm.new(hashedRow)
    #puts  preparedRecord.to_s

  end
  #puts   preparedRecord.to_s
  Oacm.import preparedRecord, :validate => true
end
```

This is the error message I get:
   `OCIError: ORA-02289: sequence does not exist: INSERT INTO "OACM" ("ID_ACM","DESCR","GP_ACM_TYPE_FK","CHAN_FK","DT_START","DT_END","EXT_CODE_REF","FLG_BURN","LAYOUT_CODE","MAX_NUM","FLG_DPL","FLG_DEF","FLG_STATE","USR_INS","TS_INS","USR_DEL","TS_DEL","USR_UPD","TS_UPD","VER_NO","ORD_NO","CPCCCHK","TS_DPL") VALUES(id_acm.nextval,'DESCR','001','001',TO_DATE('01-APR-10','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'),TO_DATE('30-APR-11','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'),'','0','2',0,'3','','0',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,3,TO_TIMESTAMP('13-APR-11 18:21:24','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS:FF6'),0,NULL,NULL,TO_TIMESTAMP('3','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS:FF6')) (ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid)`

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For what it's worth, my reading of the ActiveRecord [documentation](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/set_sequence_name/class) and other notes on the web such as [this](https://github.com/zdennis/activerecord-import/issues/40) is that it's not possible. The Oracle adapter uses and requires a sequence for id generation and, more importantly, ActiveRecord doesn't allow the value of it's `id` to be set from outside. The error you are seeing is the result of the `id_acm.nextval` SQL expression which assumes `id_acm` is a sequence. I don't think anything the ar-extensions gem could be doing could get around that situation.

Comment: Even I've made a lot of research and tests before posting here and sadly I think you are right